# Change chart.js options based on window width

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm pretty new to chart.js and HTML5 canvases, but I was able to put something together.

What I need to do now is be able to change the `xAxes.display` based on the width of the window. I assume this involves a `function` within the `scales.xAxes.display` item, but I'm not sure how. Any recommendations of where I can find more info on how to do this?

```js
var allTimeAll = $("#my-chart");
var allTimeAllChart = new Chart(allTimeAll, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Confirmed',
      data: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="my-chart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us introduce a new option `hideXAxesWhenChartIsXXS`. This option will enable hiding of all x-axes when the chart's width is less than 480 pixels. The `hideXAxesWhenChartIsXXS` option will be read by the `toggleXAxesDisplayPlugin` plugin. If the option is defined and `true`, then the plugin will decide whether the x-axes will be displayed or not based on the chart's new width, every time the chart is resized (that covers first-time drawing of the chart as well).

Talk is cheap, so [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9957gjx2/) is the code. The code is also available below.

```js
// Hides x-axes, when the chart is XXS.
var toggleXAxesDisplayPlugin = {
  // Runs on resize.
  resize: function(chartInstance, newChartSize) {
    // If the option is defined and `true`.
    if (chartInstance.config.options.hideXAxesWhenChartIsXXS) {
      if (newChartSize.width < 480) {
        // Iterate all x-axes.
        chartInstance.config.options.scales.xAxes.forEach(function(axis) {
          // Hide axis.
          axis.display = false;
        });
      } else {
        // Iterate all x-axes.
        chartInstance.config.options.scales.xAxes.forEach(function(axis) {
          // Show axis.
          axis.display = true;
        });
      }
    }
  }
};

Chart.pluginService.register(toggleXAxesDisplayPlugin);

var allTimeAll = $("#my-chart");
var allTimeAllChart = new Chart(allTimeAll, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Confirmed',
      data: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }]
    },
    // If this option is defined and `true`, then the plugin's functionality will be activated.
    hideXAxesWhenChartIsXXS: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="my-chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @xnakos. This is extremely helpful!